# How to set DynamicResource value in Setter object in code?

Tags: xamarin.forms

XAML example:

```
    <Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="VisualElement">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryColor}" />
    </Style>
```

How to do it in code?

```
    Style MyStyle = new Style(typeof(VisualElement))
    {
        Setters =
        {
            new Setter 
            {
                Property = BackgroundColorProperty,
                Value = ???
              //Valye = new DynamicResourceExtension { Key = "PrimaryColor" } !!! not working
            }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be achieved by [Dynamic style inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/dynamic#dynamic-style-inheritance).

> Deriving a style from a dynamic style can't be achieved using the Style.BasedOn property. Instead, the Style class includes the `BaseResourceKey` property, which can be set to a dictionary key whose value might dynamically change.

```
var tealSearchBarStyle = new Style (typeof(SearchBar)) {
    BaseResourceKey = "searchBarStyle",
            ...
};
```

Comment: This way you miss whole point of Dynamic Resources! It is exactly the same as Static Resources in XAML. If you change the color at runtime your style won't update the UI control.

Comment: You are correct , please check my update .

Answer (score 0):

Check Microsoft documentation :

```
public class DynamicStylesPageCS : ContentPage
{
    bool originalStyle = true;

    public DynamicStylesPageCS ()
    {
        ...
        var baseStyle = new Style (typeof(View)) {
            ...
        };
        var blueSearchBarStyle = new Style (typeof(SearchBar)) {
            ...
        };
        var greenSearchBarStyle = new Style (typeof(SearchBar)) {
            ...
        };
        ...
        var searchBar1 = new SearchBar { Placeholder = "These SearchBar controls" };
        searchBar1.SetDynamicResource (VisualElement.StyleProperty, "searchBarStyle");
        ...
        Resources = new ResourceDictionary ();
        Resources.Add ("blueSearchBarStyle", blueSearchBarStyle);
        Resources.Add ("greenSearchBarStyle", greenSearchBarStyle);
        Resources ["searchBarStyle"] = Resources ["blueSearchBarStyle"];

        Content = new StackLayout {
            Children = { searchBar1, searchBar2, searchBar3, searchBar4,    button    }
        };
    }
    ...
}
```

[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/dynamic)

Comment: I know how to set DynamicResource on element but that not what I need! I want to set it in Style object itself with Setter.